# Applied nonlinear dynamics: the onset of chaos in biological cycles (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I have seen some applied research in the onset of chaos in the study of current regulation in the human heart and the transition into cardiac arrest.

I would like to review any literature that exists on the topic of period doubling and the onset of active labor contractions in full-term pregnant women.

Comment: I advise you to start with google.com.

Comment: @Artem I did Google "chaos period doubling labor contractions". This question is now the highest ranked result.